# Testing controllers of a Rails shopify app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, shopify

I have a Rails app created through shopify_app gem and I'm trying to test my controllers using rspec. Since all my controllers inherit from `ShopifyApp::AuthenticatedController`, all testing requests get blocked by authentication, so I can't test my controllers.

I've seen a few suggestions of bypassing the authentication by stubbing the session like so:

`session[:shopify] = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(domain)`

But that still doesn't work for me. The requests seems to get redirected (response code 302).

I'm sure a lot of people stumbled upon this. But after a day of googling I couldn't find a working solution. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session object needs to be stubbed from @request, like so:

```
@request.session[:shopify] = shop.id
@request.session[:shopify_domain] = shop.shopify_domain
```

I received a detailed answer [in this post](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/testing-a-rails-app-created-through-shopify_app-gem-415552) on the Shopify forum.

Comment: Doesn't work... It still redirects to /login. Anyone has got it working with Rails 5 and RSpec?

Comment: https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/testing-a-rails-app-created-through-shopify_app-gem-415552 worked for me